# diskSpoolBufferSizeMB in ehcache configuration mean?

Tags: spring, ehcache

I have the following configuration in my project for ehcache implementation. What does the attribute diskSpoolBufferSizeMB mean?

```
<defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30" maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</defaultCache>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [indicated here](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.10.1/net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration.html#diskSpoolBufferSizeMB), it allows you to control the size of the buffer before writing mappings to disk when using a disk store.

`30` is the default value so unless you encounter specific performance issue that can be tracked to disk writes buffering, I would remove that bit from the config and forget about it.